# How to write a sql query to get data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get numOfItem from table BUY using ticketTypeId and then using the BUY.userId to find in the table USER to get the gender. So I can get numOfItem from table BUY and gender from table USER. I don't know how to write this in one query. Any idea?

table structure:

TABLE BUY:

> ticketTypeId
>
> numOfItem
>
> userId

TABLE USER:

> gender

Comment: you need something to join the tables on. Can you give the full table definitions in the question, some example data, and the intended output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join your tables on a common field, in this case user id

```sql
Select b.ticketTypeId, b.numOfItem, b.userId, u.gender
From buy b inner join user u on b.userid = u.userid
Where b.ticketTypeId = <val>
```

You want to include `where` to get only needed `ticketTypeId`

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking a join between two tables is something like:

```
select table1.*,table2.*
from
table1
join table2 on table1.key=table2.key
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add userId in the table user
2. join the tables with inner join in the select statement

   `select a.*,b.* from [user] a inner join [buy] b on a.userid = b.userid`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a join. [Here is an link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
 SELECT tb1.ticketId, tb1.numOfItem, tb1.userId, tb2.gender
 FROM Table1 as tb1
 JOIN Table2 as tb2
 ON tb1.userId = tb2.userId
```